# AJAX in Bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to use AJAX to dynamically load html pages with the click of a Bootstrap dropdown, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a onclick = "$('#ajax').load('index.html');" href = "#">Project 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Project 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Project 3</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

and then later I create the div for the ajax to load in.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "demo-row">
    <div class = "col-xs-8" id="ajax">
    </div>
```

Finally, the AJAX itself (on a separate file).

```
function loadAjax(file)
{
$(document).ready(function()

    {

    //Target the div with id of result

    //and load the content from the specified url

    //and the specified div element into it:
    var fileName = new String(file);
    var ending = " #ajax > *";
    fileName = fileName.concat(ending);
    $('#ajax').load(fileName);


    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the whole `var ending =...` part but you could really just put `$('#ajax').load('index.html');` in your onclick attribute instead of loadAjax

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that still does not work. Why is that?

Comment: Add href="#" to the first <a> element

Comment: Once again, thanks. But that still doesn't load anything. Is it possible that there is some other issue?

Comment: Are there any errors being thrown that you can see in the console? Can you update your post to reflect the changes you've made? Are you sure index.html contains anything?

Comment: Yeah sure, let me update my post. I'm positive that index.html contains things and works. As you can see, the second "button" in the dropdown menu opens it up directly for testing purposes and that works fine. If you would like, I can send you the entire code.

Comment: Why are you adding #ajax after index.html?

Comment: Whoops. Earlier, index.html used to have multiple divs and I wanted to restrict it to just the one in the ajax div, but that has changed now anyway. I updated the code. It does not work, regardless of the changes and I know for a fact that the JQUERY is running.

Comment: Are you positive that you included jQuery?.. I just tested this and it works as expected. You're not trying to load this from another domain are you? Are you seeing any errors? Is this hosted somewhere that I could see?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the power to host the code right now, though I would be glad to send it all to you if you would like. Yes I am positive that I have imported JQUERY correctly as I use it elsewhere in the same code.

Comment: When you say that you tested this what do you mean exactly?

Comment: <!--Load JQuery-->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Thats how I load JQUERY

Comment: I mean, I created 2 html files, one contained a bunch of random letters and the other contained an <a> that loaded the first html file into a <div>. If you want to send me an email: mynamesconnor[AT]gmail.com

Comment: It could just be stackoverflow's formatting but it looks like you forgot a " at the end of the src= in your <script> tag?... should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: sent it :). Hopefully it helps

Comment: Just the formatting BTW

Comment: I haven't gotten anything yet...

Comment: mynamesconner[at]gmail.com right?

Comment: mynamesconnOR@gmail.com

Comment: Yep. A lot of times browsers don't allow local files to be loaded using AJAX. Can you install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (if you're on a PC) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (if you're on a Mac) and test it? Running it on a local web server should solve this

Comment: Uh yeah sure. It might take me a few minutes to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Though if you could tell me how to test it that would be great :)

Comment: Are you downloading MAMP or WAMP?

Comment: WAMP, the rest of this message is to satisfy the character requirement

Comment: Well I mean just install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) and it's all a GUI so it's really easy to figure out. Just install it then go to c:\wamp\www and move your website to that folder then go to localhost. Here's a youtube video if you need more help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3j5lxcV_320

Comment: WOW thank you so much :)))). It works nearly perfectly. Now I just have to figure out why it is not restricting itself to a grid. Thank you